# Add text to a button with an icon Segoe MDL2 Assets font

Tags: c#, visual-studio

VS WPF

My problem is that I have a button with Segoe MDL2 Assets icons font But I also want to add text in the button right next to the icon the problem is that when u type anything in it turn into little squares. [image]

Comment: the button text can have only one font, you can capture the font glyph into an image and create an icon button with text

Answer (score 0):

[image]

WPF button elements can have anything as content. Images, text, and even another button. To be short, any WPF graphic.
So you could have a TextBlock with two Runs, where one has your icon font, and the other a regular font.

Comment: Hi Max, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)